# Pause updates from store when leaving page

Tags: angular, redux, ionic2, ngrx, reselect

I am developing an Ionic2 App with **ngrx**.

To select data from my store I am using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

I have some pages that use the same data(from the same reducer), but in combination with other reducers data, depending on the current page (this means that each page has its own reselector, but each one of this selectors has at least one argument in common with the other reselectors. So whenever one of these arguments changes all reselectors of these pages need to be recomputed).

It looks something like this:

```
page1 = createSelector(fromState1.getData, fromCommonState.getData,(data, commonData) => {...});
page2 = createSelector(fromState2.getData, fromCommonState.getData,(data, commonData) => {...});
page3 = createSelector(fromState3.getData, fromCommonState.getData,(data, commonData) => {...});
```

The concern I have is that if there are many pages whenever the common state changes all selectors are recomputed, even if I would just need to recompute the one used by the current page. I think this could become a big performance issue if the selectors need to do complicated stuff.

Is there a way to "pause" getting updates from the store until I get back to that page? In this way only the selector of the current page would be recomputed.

Or is there another way to avoid the unnecessary calculations?

Answer (score 0):

I create selectors in a common file (selectors.ts) when they are used across the **entire app** (or more than one smart component).  For your case, why don't you just keep it simple and place the selector in the smart component (the page)? That way its only calculated and subscribed to when needed.

`reselect` is used heavily with libraries that are not using Observables and data actually gets pushed on every state change. With a library like ngrx this gain is negligible, unless your working with lots of data.  To me, this is a premature optimisation.

To pause state, you could maintain the current page state somewhere in your store, then use a filter to perform the heavy action only when the page in the state matches.

```
let page3 = createSelector(
fromState3.getData, fromCommonState.getData,
(data, commonData) => {
    if(fromState3.selected) { 
      // Large computation
    }
});
```